# Is there a way to achieve type narrowing by checking with a function?

Tags: typescript, narrowing, type-narrowing

```
class A {}
class B extends A {
  bb() { ... }
}

function isB(obj: A) {
  return obj instanceof B;
}

const x: A = new B(); // x has type A
if (isB(x)) {
  x.bb(); // can I get x to have type B?
}
```

I know that if I have `x instanceof B` in the condition it will work. But can I do it through `isB()`?

Comment: Why not cast it?

Comment: @jhpratt Casting doesn't exist in Typescript since types are purely compile time information. You're thinking of type assertions, I assume. The obvious downside is that it makes the code harder to maintain and it isn't refactoring-safe.

Comment: @IngoBürk is this not a cast? `(<B>x).bb()`

Comment: @jhpratt I'm working with existing code that has these isType() functions already, and I'd like to type less

Comment: @benwaffle No, that's a type assertion, not a cast. Casting is the process of actually converting between data types at runtime. Type assertions produce absolutely no code when transpiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript supports this with a special return type, `X is A`. You can read about this more in their section on [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

For your example, you might type it like this:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {
  bb() { ... }
}

function isB(obj: A): obj is B { // <-- note the return type here
  return obj instanceof B;
}

const x: A = new B(); // x has type A
if (isB(x)) {
  x.bb(); // x is now narrowed to type B
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for